# Truncate Double in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using the `DateDiff()` function to calculate an age.

```
Dim a As Double
a = DateDiff("d", Me.Age, Me.ApptDate) / 365
```

I want to get the truncated value and NOT the rounded value.

I just want the whole number - No decimals.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe you are after the [**INT()**](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/int.php) function:

```
Dim a As Double
a = Int(DateDiff("d", Me.Age, Me.ApptDate) / 365)
```

Or have you tried doing the following:

```
Dim a As Integer
a = DateDiff("d", Me.Age, Me.ApptDate) / 365
```

Comment: I believe that rounds the number. Not truncates as I was hoping for.

Comment: No, I don't think so. The `CInt()` would round the number, but `Int()` should not round the number.  Are you working with negative numbers?

Comment: No I'm not. Here's what I'm getting.

Comment: I'm using datediff with 06/03/1947 and 10/02/2012. This gives me 64.99.... but when I use the int() I get 65 not 64

Comment: My appologies! It is working! 

Thank you very much!!